# how to deserialize this json on vb.net?

Tags: arrays, json, vb.net

i have this data in json format:

```json
{
   "status":{
      "timestamp":"2021-01-07T17:13:48.471Z",
      "error_code":0,
      "error_message":null,
      "elapsed":12,
      "credit_count":1,
      "notice":null,
      "total_count":4115
   },
   "data":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Bitcoin",
         "symbol":"BTC",
         "slug":"bitcoin",
         "num_market_pairs":9732,
         "date_added":"2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
         "tags":[
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "sha-256",
            "store-of-value",
            "state-channels"
         ],
         "max_supply":21000000,
         "circulating_supply":18593700,
         "total_supply":18593700,
         "platform":null,
         "cmc_rank":1,
         "last_updated":"2021-01-07T17:12:02.000Z",
         "quote":{
            "USD":{
               "price":39362.167971369854,
               "volume_24h":78135138852.86674,
               "percent_change_1h":2.61231359,
               "percent_change_24h":12.47756102,
               "percent_change_7d":36.98956944,
               "market_cap":731888342609.2596,
               "last_updated":"2021-01-07T17:12:02.000Z"
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "id":1027,
         "name":"Ethereum",
         "symbol":"ETH",
         "slug":"ethereum",
         "num_market_pairs":5934,
         "date_added":"2015-08-07T00:00:00.000Z",
         "tags":[
            "mineable",
            "pow",
            "smart-contracts"
         ],
         "max_supply":null,
         "circulating_supply":114155463.749,
         "total_supply":114155463.749,
         "platform":null,
         "cmc_rank":2,
         "last_updated":"2021-01-07T17:12:02.000Z",
         "quote":{
            "USD":{
               "price":1261.606649005652,
               "volume_24h":39345516218.36576,
               "percent_change_1h":3.1558102,
               "percent_change_24h":7.80752209,
               "percent_change_7d":71.81090319,
               "market_cap":144019292086.06207,
               "last_updated":"2021-01-07T17:12:02.000Z"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

and, in vb.net, with special paste i got this definition:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property status As Status
    Public Property data() As Datum
End Class

Public Class Status
    Public Property timestamp As Date
    Public Property error_code As Integer
    Public Property error_message As Object
    Public Property elapsed As Integer
    Public Property credit_count As Integer
    Public Property notice As Object
    Public Property total_count As Integer
End Class

Public Class Datum
    Public Property id As Integer
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property symbol As String
    Public Property slug As String
    Public Property num_market_pairs As Integer
    Public Property date_added As Date
    Public Property tags() As String
    Public Property max_supply As Integer
    Public Property circulating_supply As Integer
    Public Property total_supply As Integer
    Public Property platform As Object
    Public Property cmc_rank As Integer
    Public Property last_updated As Date
    Public Property quote As Quote
End Class

Public Class Quote
    Public Property USD As USD
End Class

Public Class USD
    Public Property price As Single
    Public Property volume_24h As Single
    Public Property percent_change_1h As Single
    Public Property percent_change_24h As Single
    Public Property percent_change_7d As Single
    Public Property market_cap As Single
    Public Property last_updated As Date
End Class
```

but when i try with this command to deserialize

```
Dim m As IEnumerable(Of Rootobject) = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IEnumerable(Of Rootobject))(res)
```

i get this error:

```cs
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object 
    (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CoinMarketCap.Rootobject]' 
    because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) 
    to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a
    JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a 
    normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a
    collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a 
    JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force 
    it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'status', line 1, position 10.'
```

im stucked... any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Datum` should be `data` or vice versa perhaps so it knows what it is?

Comment: `data` is `List(Of Datum)` in `Public Property data As List(Of Datum)`: that's what you want to loop over, not the RootObject, which is a single object (as the answer is telling you)

Comment: changed to Public Property data As List(Of Datum) and error continues...

Comment: More than one problem there: `tags` is `Public Property tags As List(Of String)` (avoid this format for properties: `Public Property tags() As String`, since this creates *confusion*, that's a single string, not an array), `circulating_supply`, `max_supply` and `total_supply` are Double and not Integer values and you also have to handle null values, so decorate with `<JsonProperty(NullValueHandling:=NullValueHandling.Ignore)>`. All Single should be Double, `last_updated` is DateTimeOffset, not Date...

Comment: Thanks Jimi. All changes you tell made and the error continues... :-(

Comment: Are you still trying to deserialize to an `IEnumerable(Of Rootobject)`? Because that is not going to happen. If you have changed the code (fixing the obvious errors in the class model definition), then post the updated code. Assuming this is the complete JSON you're handling.

Answer (score 0):

> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or **change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object**.

In other words, change

```
Dim m As IEnumerable(Of Rootobject) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of IEnumerable(Of Rootobject))(res)
```

to

```
Dim m As Rootobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(res)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. if i do this, i can't do a "for each" for every result. I show a result for only one iine. I will update the info with more data. Sorry for that

Comment: Your JSON has only one root object, so it does not make sense to "for each" through "them". However, if you want to loop through all *data items*, you can just do `For Each item In m.data` afterwards.